DOS namespaces, Win32 API to distinguish between them
Windows has DOS namespaces, but it seems even one user can have more than one DOS namespace, e.g. one on the desktop, and a ssh login to the same user on the same machine gets a separate DOS namespace.
How are they separated? Logon ID?
Which Win32 API can I use to see whether two programs running as the same user have the same or different DOS namespace, e.g. something like GetDOSNameSpaceID()

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/defining-an-ms-dos-device-name

You can use winobj to view the devices in the object manager.

you probably mean \Sessions\0\DosDevices\LogonId.Hi-LogonId.Low directories. you can open \Sessions\0\DosDevices and enumerate subfolders by NtQueryDirectoryObject. names of subdirectories usually have format LogonId.Hi-LogonId.Low where LUID LogonId corresponded to some logon session - you can pass it to LsaGetLogonSessionData. also enum this sessions by LsaEnumerateLogonSessions

have the same or different DOS namespace - open process token and call GetTokenInformation with TokenStatistics - look for TOKEN_STATISTICS::AuthenticationId
